# Update statement: Error: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate

Tags: sql, sql-update, amazon-redshift

I get this error when I try to update a column of Table 1 that is like a column of Table 2.

Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate.

```
update test
   set category = t1.category
from category_type t1, test t2
where t2.link ilike '%' || t1.type || '%'
and t2.link ilike '%.nike.com/%';
```

Category_Type Table shown below:

```
type       category
sandals     shoes
boots       shoes
t-shirts    apparel
-pants      apparel
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know Redshift, but in Postgres you must not repeat the target table in the `FROM` clause of an `UPDATE` statement:

```
update test t2
   set category = t1.category
from category_type t1  --<< do NOT repeat the target table here
where t2.link ilike '%' || t1.type || '%'
  and t2.link ilike '%.nike.com/%';
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to join with a subquery like this:

```
update test set category = t1.category
from (
    select c.category, t.link
    from category_type c, test t
    where t.link ilike '%' || c.type || '%'
        and t.link ilike '%.nike.com/%';
) t1
where test.link = t1.link
```

The [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Examples_of_UPDATE_statements.html) have join examples further down the page. The last example shows the benefit of the subquery.

The basic form of this query is:

```
update target set val=t2.val
from (
    select t.id, o.val
    from target t
    join other o on o.id=t.id
) t2
where target.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Tried that. But I still get an error: relation "t1" does not exist.
update temp set category = t1.category
from (
    select c.category, t.link
    from category_type c, temp t
    where t.link ilike '%' || c.type || '%'
        and t1.link ilike '%.nike.com/%'
) t1
where temp.link = t1.link;

Comment: I'll try and come up with an example I can run on my cluster.

Comment: Looks like my example has an error in the where clause of the sub-select...I can't reference t1 from there. Will fix.

Comment: Thanks! Unable to reference t1 outside the window

Comment: If you run just the inner select does it give you a list of categories and links like you'd expect?

Comment: Yes, it does..!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue `Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate` only comes when you are updating a table and join condition is also there in update.
To come out from this kind of issue you need to put join inside the () and use where clause outside of parenthesis with primary Key.

I was also facing the same issue then I have taken primary key column of target table where we are updating.

**Initial Query:**
[image]

**Final Query:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following example returns an error because the FROM clause does not support outer joins to the target table:

```
update category set catid=100 
from event left join category cat 
on event.catid=cat.catid 
where cat.catgroup='Concerts';
```

Below is the error:

> ERROR:  Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate

If the outer join is required for the UPDATE statement, you can move the outer join syntax into a subquery:

```
update category set catid=100
from
(
   select event.catid 
   from event left join category cat 
   on event.catid=cat.catid
) eventcat
where category.catid=eventcat.catid and catgroup='Concerts';
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Examples_of_UPDATE_statements.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate
```

`Amazon Redshift SQL` does not support `Left`, `right`, and `full outer` joins in the `FROM` clause of an `UPDATE` statement; so in that case the query return this error.
OR If you do not specify the table being updated in the join i.e the where clause must have the updated table as part of a predicate.