# Redshift: ERROR: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

First of all for those who might say this is duplicate question, I checked this [Update statement: Error: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368086/update-statement-error-target-table-must-be-part-of-an-equijoin-predicate)
 but this didn't help me as my scenario is quite different one.

Coming to the question,

I am trying to join two tables and performing an update. Here is my query:

```
UPDATE table1 SET f1 = table2.f1,f2 = table2.f2,f3 = table2.f3 FROM table2 where (table1.f1 = table2.f1 OR (table1.f1 is null and table2.f1 is null)) AND (table1.f2 = table2.f2 OR (table1.f2 is null and table2.f2 is null))
```

For this query I am getting error: ERROR:  Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate.

But as I see target table is already used in equijoin, why am I getting this error?
Moreover I need to match for both source and target null values, so I am using `is null` check. If I skip that and execute a normal join query as below, it doesn't give any error.

```
UPDATE table1 SET f1 = table2.f1,f2 = table2.f2,f3 = table2.f3 FROM table2 where table1.f1 = table2.f1 AND table1.f2 = table2.f2
```

What is wrong is first query then? after all there are extra brackets and condition which according to me shouldn't make much difference.

Just being curious, I tried couple of queries in redshift.

```
1. UPDATE table1 SET f1 = table2.f1,f2 = table2.f2,f3 = table2.f3 FROM table2 where (table1.f1 = table2.f1 OR (table1.f1 is null and table2.f1 is null)) -- Failed with same error.

2. UPDATE table1 SET f1 = table2.f1,f2 = table2.f2,f3 = table2.f3 FROM table2 where (table1.f1 = table2.f1 OR (table1.f1 is null and table2.f1 is null)) AND (table1.f2 = table2.f2) -- Passed

3. UPDATE table1 SET f1 = table2.f1,f2 = table2.f2,f3 = table2.f3 FROM table2 where (table1.f1 = table2.f1 OR (table1.f1 is null and table2.f1 is null)) OR (table1.f2 = table2.f2) -- Failed with same error
```

Looks like it is failing only when the last condition is `OR` and passing when it is `AND`, Very very very surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
UPDATE table1
     SET f1 = table2.f1,f2 = table2.f2,f3 = table2.f
     FROM table2 
     WHERE table1.f1 = table2.f1 AND
           (table1.f2 = table2.f2 OR (table1.f2 is null and table2.f2 is null));
```

If so, you can break this into multiple updates.

Comment: You missed -  OR (table1.f1 is null and table2.f1 is null). Other than that I am doing exactly that.

Comment: @Surajhk . . . My question is if this works.  If it does, you can split the update into multiple updates pretty easily.  Your version doesn't work, if I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

An equijoin predicate is strictly when you have only `=` operator evaluated and if there are multiple conditions it can only be an intersection (you can only use `AND`, not `OR`). I don't know exactly why is it implemented in such way but I suppose it has good reasons behind it with something related to the parallelization. More complex logic requires materializing it through subquery.

The first query does not conform with these requirements. And the solution is the same - any time you want to do something more complex than equijoin you wrap your more complex join into a subquery and equijoin it to the updated table then.